# Is this correct for calculating the nth root?

Tags: c#

For positive real numbers the rth root is given as e^(ln(x)/r)
For negative real numbers if r is odd the rth root is given as -e^(ln|x|/r)
If r is even then the real rth root of a negative number does not exist

```
static double rthRoot (double r, double x)
{
    double y;

    if (x > 0)
    {
        y = Math.Exp((Math.Log(x)) / r);
    }

    if (r+1 % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (x < 0)
        {
            y = -(Math.Exp((Math.Log(Math.Abs(x))) / r));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest way to check this is to see if gives the right result when you pass in values where you know the result. If it returns the correct result for those cases then it should be OK for others.

Comment: It will be correct once you return y :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in your code:

1. You are not returning a value in `rthRoot`. You need to return `y` which will oblige you to solve an additional issue; what to do with a call like `rthRoot(2, -4)`. Do you want to return a specific value (`double.Nan`), do you want to throw an `ArgumentException` or...?
2. `if (r + 1 % 2 == 0)` is not doing what you think its doing. Your code is equivalent to `if (r + (1 % 2) == 0)` which is clearly not what you want. The correct code should be `if ((r + 1) % 2 == 0)` or the simpler and more readable `if (r % 2 != 0)` which is the standard way to check for oddity.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. When I put return y; at the end of the method rthRoot i get an error saying use of unassigned variable y. I use rthRoot above under main so i am unsure what is wrong now

Comment: @ConorWalsh What value does `y` have if I call `rthRoot(2, -4)`? Mentally step through your code and spot where you've set `y`'s value before reaching `return y;`.

Comment: @ConorWalsh The answer is nowhere. C# does not allow the use of unitinialized variables. In case of local variables, you need to *explicitly* initialize them yourself. In your case, a good option would be to initialize `y` at the declaration point with `double y = double.Nan;`, this way the changes in your code would be minimal.